# subjunctive followed by indicative

Tags: subjunctive-mood, mood

I have a question about the use of the subjunctive in this sentence: If all the schools were to implement this program, which now exists only in the lower grades, then five years from now we will not have parents complaining that their teen-aged children still can't read.

There are a lot of internet examples that follow this pattern. Example: If that were to happen, then we will take appropriate action.

Would it be better to substitute "would" for "will" in both examples, or "should" for "were to"?

Comment: "should" is not a substitute for "were to". You could instead say "If all the schools *implemented* this scheme ..." - This is still subjunctive and so you still need "would" later on.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with one of two sentences, but mixing the two like this isn't correct. Either:

"If all the schools were to implement this program, which now exists only in the lower grades, then five years from now we **would** not have parents complaining that their teen-aged children still can't read."

Or:
"If all the schools implement this program, which now exists only in the lower grades, then five years from now we will not have parents complaining that their teen-aged children still can't read." **(remove were to)**